# redis-cli not working on linux

Tags: redis

I have installed redis onn linux.
redis sever started correctly however when I try to start redis-cli I get this error

bash: redis-cli: command not found

file redis-cli  output is

ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=0x5fe1c6d3da13df88f2ea826ac762f088c29b81d5, not stripped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `redis-cli` is present, reading your answer. Check this with `which redis-cli`.

I've installed redis on several linux machines, normally it goes very smooth. I guess you've run into a special case.

Here's my thoughts:

It might be a dynamic linking issue.

So check the headers with `dump -H -X64 redis-cli`.
In the headers, you can see which shared objects it is trying to find. There might be a shared object from another package in the way, for example a 32-bit only one. Ugly, and wrong, but it happens.

Use the `ldd` runtime dependency checker to see what those headers actually result in on your system. Install it when not present. Then simply run `ldd redis-cli`.

Now you've figured out what's wrong, you can do several things.

1) Remove the conflicting package, if possible.

2) Use the `LIBENV` environment variable, to set the search path for shared objects, prior to starting the process

3) Use the `-blibpath` linker option at compile/link time to alter the header, giving it a different search path. The `-bnolibpath` could also help you.

4) Patch the header afterwards. There are tools for this. This is generally not the preferred way to go.

Hope this helps, TW

**Edit:**

Although `make`, `make test`, and `make install` were always fine, the server install script `install_server.sh` was always a bit buggy. This has just been fixed in 2.8.8. I recommend using the latest version.

**Edit 2:**

The OP's problem turned out to have nothing to do with dynamic linking, it was a simple PATH issue. I leave the answer as is, for historical purposes.

Comment: I have installed 2.8.8 only.  I used this link to install the redis (used 2.8.8 install instead of 2.6).
Somehow redi-server is working. Also ldd redis-cli and redis-server gives exactly the same output. 
Not sure where is the problem.

I might be asking too much. Do you have a link which has detailed steps on installing redis

Answer (score 11):

I don't know what's the reason 
but when I run the using this command

`/usr/local/bin/redis-cli`  it works

but when I run redis-cli from the `/usr/local/bin/` folder I get the error

```
bash: redis-cli: command not found
```

Looks like some path issue

Comment: Yes, /usr/local/bin seems not to be in your `PATH`. Edit your .profile to add it (there are other ways, this is an easy one). The reason for `command not found`: not even `.` (the current dir) is in your path. This is good practice, I would not change that. If you issued `./redis-cli` is would have worked. Details steps on installing redis: see the `README` file that comes with the .tar.

Answer (score 4):

If you built from source and you're in the default `redis-stable` directory that contains the source, you should be able to start the cli by running:

`./src/redis-cli`

Answer (score 0):

This maybe happening because the executable isn't in path. In order to solve this, you can try copying `redis-cli` on the `/usr/local/bin/` folder with this command:

```
sudo cp /src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/
```