# How can I see what's in redis's memory on heroku?

Tags: heroku, redis

I used redis for the first time to cache a computationally-expensive fragment. It works great. To further my learning, I'd like to query redis to examine what's it's storing, the expiry, any metadata it captures, and simply to learn how to use redis.

How can query redis on heroku?

#### What I tried

I tried shelling into the dyno with `heroku ps:exec`

Then tried using the redis-cli

```
redis
# -bash: redis: command not found
redis-cli
#-bash: redis-cli: command not found
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22756000/5783745) I tried looking in a handful of places:

```
ls /bin | grep redis
ls /usr/local/bin | grep redis
ls /sbin | grep redis
```

but didn't find anything.

I noted I can get the `REDIS_URL` (and `REDIS_TLS_URL`) config variables [like so](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#create-an-instance)

```
heroku config | grep REDIS
REDIS_TLS_URL:  rediss://:asdfasdfasdf@ec2-12-345-67-890.compute-1.amazonaws.com:31840
REDIS_URL:      redis://:asdfasdfasdf@ec2-12-345-67-890.compute-1.amazonaws.com:31839
```

but I'm not sure if I can shell directly into these or query them from my terminal somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's easy, just run

```
heroku redis:cli
```

Although that command isn't provided on the [heroku redis](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis) addon page, it is documented here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-heroku-redis-using-cli

Comment: to get all keys from redis you can KEYS * once under cli

Comment: Worth noting that if you have a *lot* of keys, running `KEYS *` will block Redis for the duration of the run. Well, it does that even if you only have a few, but you'll *care* more if you have a lot of them. ;) Check out the [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan/) command if this matters to you.